# Json file is not recognising when copy json files from one s3 bucket to another s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS. I have four json files in S3 bucket. I just need to copy these four JSON files to another S3 bucket.

Below is my JSON files in the S3 bucket

1. 02-12.json
2. 03-12.Json
3. 04-12.Json
4. 05-12.Json

When copying into another bucket I am getting below results

[image]

I am using below code

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node Amazon S3
AmazonS3_node1664415190345 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"multiline": False},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="json",
    connection_options={
        "paths": ["s3://xxx-xxxx-yy/test/"],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node1664415190345",
)

# Script generated for node Amazon S3
AmazonS3_node1664415242024 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=AmazonS3_node1664415190345,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="json",
    connection_options={
        "path": "s3://xxx-yyyy-www/yyyy/ff/",
        "partitionKeys": [],
    },
    transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node1664415242024",
)

job.commit()
```

Can anyone advise what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

if you can exec to the "aws" command, "aws s3 cp" is the easiest way to copy objects between buckets